# Minimum number of elements in $S_A$, given $|A|=n$

Tags: combinatorics

**Problem:**

Suppose $A$ is a set of integers with $A=\{a_1,a_2,...a_n\}$. Define $S_A=\{r+s:r,s\in A\}$.

For example, if $A=\{1,3\}$ then $S_A=\{2,4,6\}$.

Show that, $$|S_A|\geq2n-1$$

**My attempt:**

I tried to use induction, but could not prove the inductive step. The step was, if I add another element $a_{n+1}$ to $A$, atleast $2$ new elements get added to $S_A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\}$ be the elements of $A$ in *ascending order*. Then all of
$$
a_1+a_1\\a_1+a_2\\a_2+a_2\\a_2+a_3\\\vdots\\a_{n-1}+a_n\\a_n+a_n
$$are distinct (in fact, each line is strictly larger than the one before it). One could do the same argument with $$a_1+a_1\\a_1+a_2\\a_1+a_3\\\vdots\\a_1+a_{n-1}\\a_1+a_n\\a_2+a_n\\\vdots\\a_n+a_n$$
In both cases we end up with $2n-1$ elements that are guaranteed to be distinct.

If you are set on using induction, assume that the result is true for all sets of size $n-1$. That means that if you take away the *largest element* from $A$, there are at least $2n-3$ different sums you can make. They are all smaller than twice the largest element of $A$, and they are all smaller than the sum of the largest element with the second largest element. Therefore there are at least $2n-1$ distinct sums in $A$.

Answer (score 0):

I presume there is a second part of the question  too. 
Prove that  there are exactly $2n-1$ elements iff they are in an A.P.

Comment: that's pretty obvious once you prove the first part...

Comment: yeah  .. there is another part too . construct a set  $A$ such that $|A| =10 $ and $|S_A| = 20 $.